# Clip pseudo element inside padded area

Tags: css

I have a container that has some top/bottom padding - it can't be removed or swapped for margin.

I'm trying to create a faux border (blue line) to the right hand side of the green box using a pseudo element.

The yellow area only exists to show that the green box has padding (I've clipped the background).

The issue I have is that when I use a height of 100% on the pseudo, it inherits the full height of the parent including padding, however I only want my border element to be the same height as the green box.

I CAN get the padding size (and I know how to use the calc function) but it would involve numerous media queries because the padding is fluid, and I'm trying to avoid it.

So, I was wondering whether there was any other way to make the blue border the same height as the green box.

```css
.container {
  margin: 25px;
}

.box-wrapper {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 40px 0;
  background-color: lime;
  background-clip: content-box;
  position: relative;
}

.box::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
  right: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box-wrapper">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inherit the same padding and also clip the background:

```css
.container {
  margin: 25px;
}

.box-wrapper {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 40px 0;
  background-color: lime;
  background-clip: content-box;
  position: relative;
}

.box::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
  background-clip: content-box;
  padding:inherit;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  right: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box-wrapper">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats great Temani - I've never needed to inherit padding before, so it never crossed my mind that I could.